# use angular service into JQuery event or function

Tags: jquery, angular

I have angular component and inject service into it's constructor with name `testservices` that have field with name `id`.
is it possible into jquery click function  use `testservice` and assign value to id property?

(note that i don't want use angular click because i use `jquery` component that can't implement angular click for it)

some code:

```
  export class InboxComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit  {

    private initDatatable(): void {
        var LessonDt;
        var ExamDt;
        var dtLes;
        var folId = "";
        $(".btnAddAcceptPlaceId").click(function () {

            $(".lsnMng").show();
        });
        $(".sidebar-inner").on('click', 'li.folders', function () {

            folId = $(this).attr("data-target");
            LessonDt.refresh();
        });



        LessonDt = {
            dtLes: null,

            init: function () {

                // alert('sasasa3');
                // charset=utf-8
                dtLes = $('#Inbox-data-table').DataTable({
                    // "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
                    //     const self = this;
                    //     jQuery('td', row).unbind('click');
                    //     jQuery('td', row).bind('click', () => {
                    //         rowClickHandler(data)

                    //     });
                       // console.log(data["docSubject"]);

                    //     return row;
                    // },
                    "dom": 'Bfrtip',
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "processing": true,
                    "stateSave": true,
                    "autoWidth": false,
                    "paging": true,
                    "searching": false,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "http://localhost/WCFMobile/Document.svc/GetShowInboxAngular",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        //  dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

                        // "data": '{"input":' + JSON.stringify({
                        //     WsUserName: "MobRest95Q!@",
                        //     WsPassword: "M0brE$T@u0m@ti0n95!!",
                        //     folId : "7ca19498-3d67-4b3a-82e4-c8c57b73f07f",
                        //     prsOrganizationId : "",
                        //     PrsId : "",
                        //     OrgCode:250

                        // }) + '}',


                        "data":
                            function (d) {

                                d.folId = "7ca19498-3d67-4b3a-82e4-c8c57b73f07f",
                                    d.OrgCode = "250",
                                    d.prsOrganizationId = "",
                                    d.PrsId = ""
                                return JSON.stringify(d)


                            },

                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            // alert('error');
                            console.log(xhr.responseText);

                        },

                        // "data": function (data) {

                        //    data.FacilitySite = $("#FacilitySite").val();
                        //    data.Building = $("#Building").val();
                        //    data.Manufacturer = $("#Manufacturer").val();
                        //    data.Status = $("#Status").val();
                        // }
                    },
                    "order": [[3, "desc"]],

                    "columns": [




                        {
                            "title": "موضوع",
                            width: '30%',
                            "data": "docSubject",
                            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            "searchable": false,
                            "sortable": true,
                            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {


                                 return '<div id="divclick" onclick="showMsg()">test</div>';

                            }
                        },

                    ],


                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sUrl": "/Content/dataTables.persian.txt",
                        "order": [[6, "desc"]]
                    },
                    "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 30, 100], [10, 20, 30, 100]],
                });
                var table = $('#Inbox-data-table').DataTable();



            },

            refresh: function () {
                dtLes.ajax.reload();
                var table = $('#Inbox-data-table').DataTable();


            }
        }
        $('#Inbox-data-table').on('click', 'tr,.editQuestion,.DelQuestion,.AddQuestion,.CorrectExam,.link', function () {

            var arr = $('#Inbox-data-table').dataTable().fnGetData($(this).closest("tr"));

            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            if (arr != null && $(this).attr("class") == "link") {
                return true;
            }
           ****************************************
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');  // in this line i want to use typescript router
*********************************************

            }

        });
        LessonDt.init();






      }

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {












    ngOnInit() {

        this.route.params.subscribe(
            data =>
                {
                    this.folId = data["p1"];
                    this.orgCode = data["p2"];
                    this.folName = data["p3"];
                    this.orgId = data["p4"];
                    console.log(this.folId);

                }
        )




    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: @CruelEngine i user jquery datatable into angular 6. datatable has subject column, i want when i click on that column route into another page with angular router service.

Comment: post some code to show what you've tried :)